# animationEnd Eventlistener fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

*Html:*

```
<div id="click">Click</div>
<div id="animateElement">I get animated</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#animateElement {
height: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: green;
}

.animate {
     animation: blue 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes blue {
    from {
        background: red;
    }

    to {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

*Javascript:*

```
 document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('animateElement').classList.toggle('animate');
    document.getElementById('animateElement').addEventListener('animationend',function(e){
            alert('animated');

        });


}, false);
```

First Click is ok, next Clicks fires twice, third click 4 times etc.... Is there a way to prevent this?
I tried to remove the eventlistener but i had no success...

Comment: You are adding event listeners everytime it gets clicked, i believe. Why are you nesting the event listener inside another

Comment: You also need to add false to the animationend listener

Comment: I nested it (this here is simplified code, sorry for that..) because i call a function in my animationend event that includes variables / Data from the clicked event..

Comment: Ok i realized my error. I tried to pass variables from den click event to functions i call in den animationend event. But it is much more simple, i totally disregarded the possibilty to get this data from e.target. Thank you very much you helped me a lot. Now everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Each time the `click` event listener is called, an additional `animationend` event listener is added to `#animateElement`. You can resolve this by de-nesting the registering of event listeners:

```
document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('animateElement').classList.toggle('animate');
}, false);

document.getElementById('animateElement').addEventListener('animationend',function(e) {
    alert('animated');
});
```

You might be interested in reading up on how event listeners work on the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you very much! I realized my mistake, you are absolutely right. I have now been able to solve everything very well.